# Change value/content of div that is being loaded through .after method in jquery

Tags: jquery

I know this is a simple question, but I got a hard time solving this one.

The text below the button element is generated after the DOM is loaded. The output should have a random string after a button is clicked. I learned that delegation binding should use, that's why I'm using the "on" method. However, my code doesn't work.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akoni/sy5d1t4x/)

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn123" id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.btn123').after('<br/><div id="textNi"><span style="font-family: &quot;georgia&quot; , 
               &quot;times new roman&quot; , serif;"><span style="color: #660000;">Sample ra 
               ni</span></div></span>');
});

$('#btn').on('click', '#textNi', function()
{
   $(this).text(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));
});
```

Comment: Side note: your click handler code is outside the ready - function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generated markup will look something like this:

```
└┬ #btn
 └ #textNi
```

`#textNi` is not a descendant that is found in `#btn`, but it is instead a sibling—therefore, your callback will never fire. If you look up the [`.on()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/), it says that the second argument is:

> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event.

You simply select for `#textNi` directly instead:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
   $('#textNi').text(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro for the explanation. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the code:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function()
{
    $('#textNi').text(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));
});
```